# Single Sign On (Quicklaunch) on React App Using SAML

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, saml, quicklaunch

I have encountered a problem with my React App's single sign-on (SSO) on Quicklaunch. After logging in on Quicklaunch and then it redirects to my React App I get this response.

Cannot POST /sso/login

this /sso/login is the page on the React App.

I asked for the support of Quicklaunch and they said they would return some data from the active directory like the username.

How can I check the data from Quicklaunch to check if the user exists on my React App? I feel I have missed a step.

Comment: How much are you aware on how SAML authentication works? In particular, what part of the client-side SAML protocol you already implement in your app? Depending on how you answer these questions, you either have a small technical issue with your existing implementation or a huge amount of work on learning and implementing client-side SAML.